# Searching for second word in UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have created a view with a tableview + searchbar. If searched for the first word in a string it works perfectly! Unfortunately it does not work if searched for a different word in the string. So if I would have an search for the text: bal.

And I would have the following string to look through: green bal. it would not find anything.

I currently am comparing the searchbar text with the data with this code:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

[self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

for (Product *product in self.listContent)
{

    NSComparisonResult result = [product.name compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        [self.filteredListContent product];
    }
}
NSMutableSet *tempSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:self.filteredListContent];
self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tempSet allObjects]];
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is looking for exact matches (insensitive to case as well as diacritics) using the `compare:options:range:` method in `NSString`:

```
NSComparisonResult result = [product.name compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
if (result == NSOrderedSame)
{
    [self.filteredListContent product];
}
```

Given your problem description, you wish to determine a string is contained inside another string. Use the `rangeOfString:options:` method in `NSString` instead:

```
NSRange range = [product.name rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
if (range.length > 0)
{
    [self.filteredListContent product];
}
```